# Does anybody actually run antivirus software on linux servers?

Tags: linux, centos, anti-virus

Running about 10 servers all **CentOS 6.3**. Some servers are web role *(nginx, php-fpm, node.js)*, others are database *(MySQL, MongoDB)*.

Do people actually run antivirus software on their linux servers? If so, which antivirus software is recommend? Also, how do you prevent the antivirus software from thrashing the disk i/o on database servers while running scans?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The only antivirus software running on linux servers I've heard of was to protect clients not the servers themselves.

Most popular server roles that can benefit from including antivirus are:

1. mail servers (to inoculate mail attachments)
2. file servers
3. web servers (if web application allows user file uploads)